# Python's equivalent to R's logspace_add function?

Tags: python, r

Is there a python's equivalent to R's [logspace_add](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_140.html) function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there is a function

```
 math.log1p(x)
```

which returns the natural logarithm of 1+x (base e). The result is calculated in a way which is accurate for x near zero.

otherwise if you were using numpy you could use

```
numpy.logaddexp(logA, logB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make your own...?

```
import math

def log_add(x,y):
    res = math.log(math.exp(x) + math.exp(y))
    return res
```

Comment: No - the reason the user is asking for this function is most likely because they want to avoid float underflow. Keeping a statistical program of some kind in "logspace" for as long as possible (dealing with log-probabilities rather than probabilities) avoids this problem.

Approximating summation between probabilities with log-probabilities is very useful.